# Eclipse IDE remote rebug and remote edit a legacy webapp

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, ide

I am in a bind here, what's happening is I have a legacy webapp which uses an in-memory database. The app requires 64GB of RAM just to launch and it takes at least 30 minutes to start.

I have to make updates/fixes to this application. Obviously it is impossible to launch it on my PC so everything has to be done on the server. I have considered setting up an Eclipse IDE on the Linux server where this app runs, but that introduces a set of new issues. I really would like to continue using my PC's Eclipse IDE and make edits to the app.

I am able to use the remote debugging capabilities of Eclipse IDE and launch this app from the linux server no problem.   However this is not enough.  After I make an edit, I need to be able to save/compile the file, and load this change into the server relatively quickly. I can't wait 30 minutes every time I make some updates to the app.

Can anyone recommend ideas on what to do in this scenario?  Ideally I would love to be able to launch the app in DEBUG mode inside the Linux Eclipse IDE on the server and connect to this instance using remote debugging from my local/Windows IDE.  I would like to make changes in my Windows Eclipse IDE and then quickly copy the files over to the linux server, pick them up in the Linux Eclipse IDE, compile them in the Eclipse IDE instance running in debug mode, and effectively "hot swapping" the changes,  thereby avoiding the need to wait 30 minutes for the app to start back up... However when I try to do this, there is a caveat... I can't seem to be able to launch the webapp in Linux Eclipse IDE in both DEBUG mode and also remote-debug-connect to it, the error I am getting in Eclipse is:

```
"Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice"
```

I get what is going on:  the local debugger is launching tomcat with the -agentlib:jdwp   parameter and on top of it, I am trying to force it to also start up with the same arguments and so it complains, but is there some way to trick it into allowing me to remote connect into this debug session from my Windows server?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by updating Tomcat's context.xml to support reloadable mode:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

And in the app to set it to reloadable in WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<web-app reloadable="true">
```

Now I am able to make edits in my local windows Eclipse IDE, Save them, and they automatically get updated on the server side.